# Pause play button

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click pause button, it should play button. Then I click Play button, pause button should display. I searched google and found this location.

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/HY9ns/1/"
```

This is useful for me. But I don't know how to change image instead of text. I am not knowledgeable in JQuery. Anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..
http://jsfiddle.net/HY9ns/103/

change image according to your design

Answer (score 1):

Just use two different css on the button, with two different background images, change the css instead of text:

```
$("a#button").attr("class", "play");

$("a#button").attr("class", "pause");
```

simple change to your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HY9ns/96/